# When caching vars, what is the best way to call it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you cache a var:

```
var something = $('#something');
```

I have seen that being used later as:

```
$(something).doAction();
something.doAction();
```

Is there a difference in using either? I have started using something.doAction() as it looks cleaner and easier to read. But I'd like to know if this could cause any problems?

Comment: The former is redundant. the latter is all you need.

Comment: Do you understand each of those three lines? What do you think would happen?

Comment: `$(something)` equals to `$( $( '#something' ) )`.

Comment: Calling it "caching a var" is seriously misleading. You are caching the results of a function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(...)` returns a jQuery object.

If you put a jQuery object in a variable, the variable will still hold a jQuery object in it when you check on it later, just like anything else you might put in a variable.

No magical gremlins will come and get rid of the jQuery object behind your back.
(unless you accidentally put something else in the variable elsewhere)

Comment: You should explain what's special about jQuery objects so that if you put them in a variable, the variable still holds that object later.

Comment: The key point is that there's *nothing* special in jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with jQuery.  This is just a fundamental of Javascript.

```
var x = foo();
x.something();
```

Is of course the same as `foo().something()`.  Go study programming or Javascript until this makes sense.

Comment: In particular, `$()` is no different from any other function.

Answer (score 0):

There is just hold this a jquery object to use it later or avoid repetition.

```
var $button = $('#button');

$button.click(function(){
//some code here
});

//now applying some style to it
$button.css({color:"#ccc",background:"#333"});
```

Or could be replace with

```
var $button = $('#button').css({color:"#ccc",background:"#333"});

$button.click(function(){
//some code here
});
```

Or

```
$('#button').css({color:"#ccc",background:"#333"}).click(function(){
//some code here
});;
```

Update:

Sometimes if you look for a button, jquery will return you the button, not the object so to edit or do some action you pass it as argument to the jquery constructor.

[Here a  little example](http://jsbin.com/OfUYeSU/1/edit). You are just looking for the button and jquery returns that button but if you need to apply some style,event, etc,etc, you would need to pass it as argument to the jquery contructor `($ or jQuery)`.  [And here another without the constructor that does not work](http://jsbin.com/OVUqiHU/1/edit)

Comment: I said, that is hold a query object but ok. I'll explain better

Comment: I have seen this type of var too, is the $ in $button do anything? Or is it just there to make it easier to read and use later (you know that it is a jquery object stored in the var)

Comment: @user2413333: No; that's a normal variable that happens to have a `$` in its name.

Comment: @user2413333 that just to know to that that variable holds a jquery object. But it is a normal variable

Answer (score 0):

`something` is a jQuery object and there is no need to put it in brackets with dollar sign as this:  `$(something)`

jQuery selectors return jQuery objects, which is case here `$('#something')`.

Good naming practice would be to name something as $something, so you know that variable contains jQuery object.

Also good use of $(..) example, would be wrapping html as string to get jQuery object, like this:

```
$divObject = $('<div>Some text</div>');
$divObject.text(); // value is 'Some text'
```